# Splitting up computation - setTimeout vs requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, browser, settimeout, requestanimationframe

Say I run a 2-step process during page scrolling, that I'd like to split up for performance reasons (preventing jank). I could use `setTimeout`:

```
function foo() {
    // Step 1

    setTimeout(bar, 25);
}

function bar() {
    // Step 2
}
```

However, I could also use requestAnimationFrame (rAF):

```
function foo() {
    // Step 1

    requestAnimationFrame(bar);
}

function bar() {
    // Step 2
}
```

Are there benefits of using rAF instead of a plain timeout? Note that my "Step 2" does *not* write to the DOM. I just want to yield in order to prevent jank.

Comment: What do you mean "yield it in order to prevent jank?" If you mean step 2 has a lot of computation/processing, then neither `setTimeout` nor `rAF` will help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187393/why-javascript-settimeout-is-not-multithreaded

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` should only be used for animations. It might be throttled differently (depending on the UI) than `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`.

Comment: @soktinpk If my JavaScript execution takes too long (e.g. 50ms) during a scroll event, there will be jank. If I use setTimeout, my execution yields and the browser's event loop gets a chance to perform a reflow/paint (= no jank).

Comment: @Bergi That's what the spec states, yes. I'm curious though how rAF performs, compared to setTimeout, for general-purpose computation tasks. It wouldn't be the first time, that an API's misuse has some unexpected positive side-effects :)

Comment: @Bergi  I have to disagree with you on this one :-)  RAF ticks about 60x per second.  I sometimes use even ticks to "draw" the animation and odd ticks to do calculations required for the next drawing. No harm done as long as both the drawing and calculation routines are tight and fit within the time allowed.

Comment: @markE Whoa, interesting approach :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything faster than setTimeout and requestAnimationFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906947/is-there-anything-faster-than-settimeout-and-requestanimationframe)

Comment: if your step-2 is not related to anything about updating ui or dom then you shouldn't go for rAF. Since rAF execution shouldn't exceed ~10ms ideally or it will cause some  jank on UI itself;